# Firebase JS SDK missing firebase.d.ts. Typescript error when running ionic serve

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2, typescript-typings

I am running an ionic project using AngularFire. I get typescript error when running

`ionic cordova build  --prod --release android`.

```
typescript error '/home/sebinbenjamin/workspace/myapp/node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts' not found.

    Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
        at /home/sebinbenjamin/workspace/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:232:55
        at step (/home/sebinbenjamin/workspace/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
        at Object.next (/home/sebinbenjamin/workspace/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
        at fulfilled (/home/sebinbenjamin/workspace/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
```

When checking the projects node/node_modules/firebase/ directory, there is no `firebase.d.ts`, but only `index.d.ts`.

Here's my ionic info:

```
ionic info
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v6.13.1
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Linux 4.4

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/sebinbenjamin/Android/Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I'm using `"firebase": "~4.12.0"` and `angularfire2": "~5.0.0-rc.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One temporary solution is to rename `index.d.ts` to `firebase.d.ts`, which does not seem to be causing other errors.